# Intellij Idea refactoring move "getters and setters" to the end of file

Tags: java, actionscript-3, oop, intellij-idea, refactoring

I need to rearrange some files according to same style. There are many "getters and setters" in random places. I want to move them to the bottom of file and sort by name.
Is any plugin or something to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Intellij gives you the option to automatically rearrange your code in the way that you prefer.

You can first go to `Settings->Code Style->Java` to choose the format of your code, and after that just hit `Code->Rearrange Code`.

For more information check these:

[Rearrange code Official docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/rearranging-code-using-arrangement-rules.html)

[Rearrange you code](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is to drag the methods in the outline section of eclipse

Comment: @sergey-senkov is asking for an IntelliJ solution, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If they are simple getters and setters, then you can delete the ones you have right now and then recreate them by groups.

So, after you delete them, place caret below all class members and press `Alt` + `Insert` on your keyboard, then choose `Getter and Setter` and then select member you want to create in the first batch. After that, place the caret to the end of a file and repeat the steps.

This is how I do in cases when I have pure getters and setters.